# How can I skip onResume while starting of an Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Basically I am looking to place some code in OnResume() which gets triggered only when a user pressses back from an activity that was called from this fragment but that code inside onResume() should not get executed on Start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `startActivityForResult` to start activity and `onActivityResult` will be called when you come back.

If you want the behavior you mentioned in `onResume` anyway, you may use a boolean flag:

```
boolean started = false;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(started) {
        //do your task
    } else {
        started = true;
    }
}
```

But `onActivityResult` is the good way to do this.

Comment: For startActivityForResult , It seems I have to do it from parent activity and then which fragment got the return. can I do it from fragment?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 You can also do it from fragment

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly hack-ish technique, but it works.

First you declare a boolean in the class:

```
private boolean isInitialized = false;
```

In `onResume`, you check for the value. If it is false, you set it to true. If it is true, you execute the code you want (code example at the bottom).

Remember the fragment lifecycle:

[image]
<sub>(source: [xamarin.com](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/Images/fragment_lifecycle.png))</sub>

`onResume` is the last called event when the fragment is started. So all of this has to be called in `onResume` to be properly used (if the boolean is set to `true` in onCreate it is always true in `onResume`, even on the first launch)

So basically, your `onResume` method should look like this:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(!isInitialized) isInitialized = true;
    else{
        //Your code here
    }
}
```